# Crystal reports barcode shrink when generate pdf from asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I am using following code to generate pdf from crystal report in ASP.NET MVC platform

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ClassCard()
    {

        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();

        rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "ClassCard.rpt"));
        rd.SetParameterValue("ClassName", "Kandy");
        rd.SetParameterValue("Type", "Group Theory");
        rd.SetParameterValue("year", "2016");
        rd.SetParameterValue("Student", "KDG0012");




        rd.SetDatabaseLogon("DB_74931_rmsecon_user", "snb123");


        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        try
        {
            Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return File(stream, "application/pdf", "EverestList11.pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }



    }
```

this give me pdf as below

[image]

but as you see the barcode is shrinked ,how im solve this problem in ASP.NET MVC enviroment

i saw most people say add registy key ,but i cannot do this coz this is asp.net mvc web application and im going host this app on sheared server

if im Add below regiter keys the problem will solve only for if im generate crystal report in local desktop app

[image]

Comment: Is your barcode an image our a font? Are you using a specific library to generate these barcodes?

Comment: im usning carolina barcode font https://www.carolinabarcode.com/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the crystal reports runtime has or had a well known issue that fonts shrink when reports are exported to pdf.

As you noted one (undesirable) option is to modify registry keys as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212290/font-size-is-decreased-when-exporting-crystal-report-to-pdf)  and [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3405932). Another is to compensate by sizing your fonts appropriately to allow for the shrinkage.

I opted for upgrading to Crystal reports for visual studio [version 13](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) which supports dynamic image urls but more importantly I stopped using fonts in favour of a [barcode imaging libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304804/how-can-i-generate-encode-gs1-128-or-ean128-barcode).

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the similar issue of shrinking of the font while exporting the file to PDF, this is actually the default behavior while export. In order to maintain the original font and behavior, you can check the following answers where few registry changes are suggested.

1. [Font Size Problem Crystal Report](http://www.barcodesoft.com/crystal-reports-export-pdf-font-size.aspx)
2. [Font Issue Details in Crystal Report](http://www.morovia.com/kb/Font-size-decreases-exporting-PDF-Crystal-Reports-10053.html)

Comment: thank you for help ,but im using a shared web server ,i couldnt touch its registry that the problem here